# waitforseconds() method not work not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, wait

I wrote my codes right and based on the codes in (Unity docs)

but still not working , not waiting , any help !

```
  IEnumerator wait(float waitTime)
  {
      Debug.Log("Wait"); // write this successfully
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
      Debug.Log("Waitting"); // not write it , not enter here !!
  }

  void somefunction()
  {
      StartCoroutine("wait", Resources.Load<AudioClip>("win").length);
      Debug.Log("waiting finished"); // write it directly !
  }
```

Comment: Maybe _Assets/Resouces/win.mp3_ is not found. Any errors in the console?

Comment: Call Somefunction() in to Start() then check?

Comment: @Kay No , it`s exist 100%

Comment: @RasaMohamed worked fine in Start() function

so , what`s the solution now ?

Comment: where you need to call that somefunction(), try to use in Start,  thats it

Comment: No , based on my game logic .
when the player win then (play AudioClip) , and wait for audio to complete
then load the next scene !

Comment: @RasaMohamed

I detected the problem
-----------------------------
this not worked
StartCoroutine("wait", Resources.Load<AudioClip>("win").length);
Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);

this worked fine
StartCoroutine("wait", Resources.Load<AudioClip>("win").length);
//Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel); <- this comment now

...............
what I got , it can`t wait if (Application.loadlevel exist)
he must load the level and don`t wait

Comment: Yes, Once Application is loading, cancels every threads. . . check my another solution it may suitable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetKey ("down")) { // Make here Game Wining condition
        win = true; // Make Bool variable true
    }
    if (win)
        tim += Time.deltaTime;//play here audio

    if (tim > 6.0) { // When getting finish the audio, load the level
        Debug.Log ("Load");
    }
}
```

Another solution
no need to work waitforseconds()

Answer (score 0):

You need to write logic which is decide players win. after that:

```
void decidePlayerWin(){
  /// Do your game logic and if player wins/loses etc call 
   StartCoroutine("wait", Resources.Load<AudioClip>("win").length);
}

IEnumerator wait(float waitTime)
{
    Debug.Log("Wait"); // write this successfully
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
    Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
}
```

You can apply your logic in [Update](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) method.

Like:

```
void Update(){
    //Do logic and decide wins/loses.
    if(playerWins){
       StartCoroutine("wait", Resources.Load<AudioClip>("win").length);
    }
}
```

PS: You need to understand [Coroutines](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html).